# Angular QueryList observable not triggered by child properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-observable

I have an angular application with a set of child components. I want the root component to subscribe to any changes to the children so that I can run some manual validation. I need to subscribe to both push/pop of children, and to changes to child components' properties.

However, it seems that my observable only triggers on push/pop. What am I doing wrong?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewChildren.changes.subscribe((x: QueryList<LinkComponent>) => {
        debugger;
    });
}
```

Comment: It will only emit value if the element removed or added check this;https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description

Comment: Seems like a bad design. Can you give more code about what is `viewChildren`, and what exact event you want to catch. What are you calling "push/pop" ? A new component created inside a `*ngFor` ?